# body is not covering document height

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<body>
    <img id='imgTest' src='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
html{
    height:100%;
    background:blue;
}
body{
    height:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
#imgTest{
    position:absolute;
    height:700px;
    width:200px;
    top:14px;
    left:25px;
}
```

I need body to covering the whole document height, and keep `imgTest` absolutely positioned.

here is **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SAf2a/)**

Answer (score 4):

Standard issue with absolutely positioned elements. In order to make sure the surrounding `body` element has the correct size, you need to specify it:

```
body{
    height:100%;
    background:yellow;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 714px; /* height of image + top of image */
}
```

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAf2a/3/).

Comment: Arjan, suppose that a visitor has a monitor 720px height. Body is still not covering the whole visible document !

Comment: In that case the `height: 100%` should still give the body sufficient height to cover the view port, so the background is yellow.

Comment: Arjan, but I don't know what is visitors display height? So, what I should write: `height:100%` or `min-height:...` ? I need the body to cover document height for each display height.

Comment: You should use both `height: 100%` and `min-height: 714px`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
 margin:0
```

to body CSS

Comment: That still leaves the big gap under the image.

Comment: Yup did see the scroll below. Will continue to look

Comment: Ok, how about simple removing any style for HTML and leave the body one: http://jsfiddle.net/SAf2a/5/